# Print rendered field in views-view.html.twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

I try to render a custom node field in a views-view.html.twig and it works, the only thing is that i get the machine name and not the formatted name. Please can somebody describe me what i am doing wrong?

I have tried several ways like:

```
{{ view.field.field_my_field.value(view.result[0]) | render }}
```

or

```
{{ view.field.field_my_field.value(view.result[0]) }}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

this does get the value

```
{{ view.field.field_my_field.value(view.result[0]) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is´nt working. I need the view.result (0-3).